# Running Sumo without inherent output files

Tags: output, report, sumo

I'm running Sumo using Traci. I generate my own reports, and don't like Sumo to generate any other report. My .sumocfg file also doesn't request any output (see below).
However, Sumo still generates 5 output files upon every run. Is there a way to disable that?
My running command:

```
>sumo -c ../../LuSTScenario/scenario/my.sumocfg -V False -W
```

My .sumocfg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<input>
    <net-file value="lust.net.xml"/>
    <route-files value="buslines.rou.xml,DUERoutes/local.actuated.0.rou.xml,DUERoutes/local.actuated.1.rou.xml,DUERoutes/local.actuated.2.rou.xml,transit.rou.xml"/>
    <additional-files value="vtypes.add.xml,busstops.add.xml,e1detectors.add.xml,lust.poly.xml"/>
</input>

<time>
    <begin value="0"/>
    <step-length value="1"/>
</time>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some times outputs are defined in additional files. In your case it is probably enough to remove `e1detectors.add.xml` from the file list.

Comment: Please label it as  accepted answer then. Thank you